# System.Assert Failing in VF Controller Test Class

Tags: visualforce, unit-test, controller

I'm attempting to run a test class for a custom Visualforce controller but am having an issue with my System.AssertEquals method.

Controller:

```
public without sharing class CC_LegalController {

public String Brand{get;set;}

public CC_LegalController() {
    hasAcceptedTerms = false;
    User thisUser = [select Id, AccountId, Brand__c from User where Id = :UserInfo.getUserId() ];
    if(thisUser.Brand__c == 'Brand 1'){
        Brand = 'Brand 1';
    }else{
        Brand = 'Brand 2';
    }   
}

public Boolean hasAcceptedTerms { get; set; }

public PageReference updateUser() {
    update new User(Id=UserInfo.getUserId(), Accepted_Legal_Terms__c=hasAcceptedTerms);
    return Page.CC_Home;
}
```

Test Class:

```
@IsTest global with sharing class CC_LegalController_TC { 
   @IsTest(SeeAllData=true) 
   global static void testCC_LegalController () {
       CC_LegalController controller = new CC_LegalController();
       System.assertEquals(Page.CC_Home, controller.updateUser());       
    }
```

}

The error message I am getting is `"System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: System.PageReference[/apex/cc_home], Actual: System.PageReference[/apex/cc_home]"` ... which looks equal to me.  Any guesses as to what I'm missing?  Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
System.assertEquals(Page.CC_Home.getUrl(), controller.updateUser().getUrl());
```

should fix it.

The problem is that `PageReference` doesn't implement [value equality](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/ValueObject.html) (equal when all fields are equal) semantics so only references to the same instance are equal. The `getUrl` method returns a `String` which does implement value equality.

As an aside, `Page.CC_Home` is actually a factory that creates a new `PageReference` each time. So even:

```
System.assertEquals(Page.CC_Home, Page.CC_Home);
```

fails.

Comment: That did it. Thanks not only for the solution but for the clear explanation as well.

Comment: @snoeCloud Been bemused by this myself so happy to help.